# How to turn an external flash off and reactive the incorporated one (Canon 600D)?

Tags: canon, flash, troubleshooting

After using an external flash, I took it off and, when trying to use the built-in flash incorporated to the camera, it just didn't pop up.

In the menu, it tells me that the external flash is mounted, though it's actually already off the camera.

Thanks for your help on this!

Comment: Have you try to switch off and then on the camera?

Comment: And if that doesn't work, try a factory reset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a tiny switch inside the hotshoe (if I remember correctly, on the side below one of the "rails").

If this switch is stuck the camera will think an external flash is mounted.

Comment: Look carefully and you will see there are metal spring-like shims under the 'rails. make sure they are both 'up'. There is also a switch under one, take a paper clip and slide under the shims, see if you can get the switch to pop back up.

Comment: See: http://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3083473#forum-post-39643256

Comment: Great, thanks! This actually worked out! Appreciated.